passport authorization of 3rd party app - accessing /oauth/authorize with token based user from front app
i have a website with separate fornt(vue) and backend (laravel) applications
im using passport for authentication , generating personal access token for users and storing it in front application , and sending request with Bearer authToken to backend from front app for protected routes
i have a personal client to generate these tokens
now im trying to grant another website users to access their information in my website , so i have created a new passport client for 3rd party apps
and ask for authorization from 3rd app using that client
     $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => config('mywebsite.auth_client_id'),
        'redirect_uri' => route('thisapp.callback'),
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
        'state' => Str::uuid()->toString() ,
    ]);
    
    return ['url' => config('mywebsite.mywebsite_url') .'/oauth/authorize?'.$query];

which generates a authorizations url
http://api.mywebsite.com/oauth/authorize?....

the problem is this will generate a backend route , which is protected by auth:web
users need to login in my backend directly which means i need a frontent app for login in my backend app
i tried to call this route via my front app with user token , but apparently this route is protected with web/session guard and dont recognize my front token
i've tried to change the guard in config/passport to api so the route works with token/api guard but im getting this error

"message":
"Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController::__construct():
Argument #2 ($guard) must be of type
Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard,
Laravel\Passport\Guards\TokenGuard given",

i tried to overwrite the route with auth:api middleware
Route::get('/oauth/authorize', [\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AuthorizationController::class, 'authorize'])->middleware('auth:api');

but still asking for log in when i call the route with my auth token
is there any way to call these routes with api/token logged user from front end instead of web/session in the backend ?

Just don't define the route with the web middleware?

@miken32 if you're talking about oauth/authorize ,   those are pre-defined passport  routes im not defining them

@hretic u have the 'driver' => 'passport', 'provider' => 'users', right? have u checked this(don't use the password)? can u make and distribute a personal access ?

@francisco yes i have 'driver' => 'passport', 'provider' => 'users' in the config  and  i can generate personal tokens

Ok I don’t use passport so no idea how it’s defined. Have you tried just creating a new route pointing to the same controller? Or redefining the same route using withoutMiddleware(‘web’)

I'm not familiar with Passport but there's something I don't understand. The /oauth/authorize URL is meant to show a form where users authenticate and give their consent, right? It should be a public page. It  makes no sense to protect it with a token.

@miken32 yes you can check the this part of my question  i tried to overwrite the route with auth:api middleware

@Olivier /oauth/authorize is where authenticate user gives consent for access to his account by 3rd party app , so user must be authenticate  before accessing this route that's why this route is protected by auth middleware and user will redirect to login page before accessing it (if not already logged in )

Reread my comment. I said to redefine the route without the web  middleware. If you tried this, it isn’t in your question.

don't use api routes for passport authorization, web is the most secure form for your users to get authenticated, the first issue here is you're using api guard for your SPA which isn't the best for web apps. The issue is that any script executing within your own app can steal user JWT Token.

@StanleyAloh thanx i've been reading about the auth flow and most seem to suggest not using api token in the request header .... i guess we can make it work with cookie if back/front have the same domains and we are willing to make a partially fullstack app (just for the auth) ....  but how about native mobile apps ?  this is unrelated but i wonder if they can handle it somehow in the mobile app

"user will redirect to login page before accessing it (if not already logged in)" And how will Passport know that the user is already logged in? Is that information present in the session? From what I understand, the answer is no. So, even if the user has already logged in in another browser tab, Passport has no way to know it, and the user will have to authenticate again (which is not a big deal because they need to do that only once).

@hretic your oauth server has nothing to do with your spa application, the code grant interface can be customize and has nothing to do with your spa app. for local authentication for spa simply use a personal grant. For mobile apps or third party, use authorization code grant with PCKE, a mobile app should open up a web modal and allow users to retrieve an authorization code, likewise an external web app should open up a web iframe likewise

@StanleyAloh Using an iframe is not recommended.

@Olivier well yes if you use web guard to log in , the login information are stored in cookie/session so you dont have to pass the auth token with your request , browser/server will will handle this ... and passport routes are protected with web guard
also i frame is not recommended but it makes sense if you dont want to redirect user to api domain for login

oh okay thanks for that, then you could just do a regular redirect

I think you are searching for Passport JSON APIs
Passport contains the webpages for login, you can use that to redirect to the common page to login for multiple third party applications
Also Passport contains predefined JSON APIs to issue and verify tokens of the system, for this you can use your own UI, but the common system for Authentication & Authorisation

thanx , im looking for a solution to not redirect user to backend domain for login since i have a separate front app and i perfer to do this only in my front app instead  ... which by talking with others im starting to think it's just not how passport works and i need to do it anyway

I think the primary issue you're facing is that the authorization endpoint (/oauth/authorize) is protected by the auth:web middleware which requires session-based authentication. To resolve this issue, you can user a more proper oAuth2 flow like the authorization code flow, which can handle this w/o requiring direct backend login.

@Lanre thanx yes im realizing this flow is not recommended by oauth that's why there is no build in support for what im trying to do
